# Presashop - hooks on homepage not working

Tags: prestashop

i am creating page: https://voxbook.pl with this template: https://themeforest.net/item/smartbook-book-store-responsive-prestashop-theme/23016421

I have problems with add most modules (not all) to main page and I don't know why.

For example one module posStaticBlock working with hook displayBlockPosition1 and other modules no.

What to check first?

Comment: You have to check the module you want to show on home have the hook that is placed on home page. If hook is not placed on home page then it will not show on home page.

Comment: Thank You and how to check if hook is placed on homepage?

Comment: in 1.6 have option to check , but not in 1.7 prestashop.
for 1.7 u need to check In code or check in admin design->postion